# JS Puppeteer - How to scrape a table

Tags: javascript, html, web-scraping, puppeteer

I am not too knowledgeable with Javascript or Puppeteer and I was wondering how to scrape the following table:

[image: Table I Want To Scrape]

I want to scrape everything within body which are all `<tr>...</tr>` which have `<td class="className">...</td>` 
[image]

Any solutions?

Comment: @Rob - the image is actually more useful in this case.

Comment: @pguardiario Are you saying the image cannot be duplicated with text?

Comment: I'm saying images of elements panels are often more useful than pasting tons of html. It's not the same thing as images of code.

Comment: @pguardiario The image of the code is the code he wants you to help scrape. That it's in a panel means nothing. He needs to enter it as text as required by the rules I link to and quote. There is no reason not to.

Comment: That's not code. Feel free to disagree but I'm the one answering it and I say there's nothing useful about posting the html in this case.

Answer (score 1):

That might look something like:

```
await page.evaluate (() => {
  return [...document.querySelectorAll('.tbrdr tbody tr')].map(tr => {
    return [...tr.querySelectorAll('td.className')].map(td => td.innerText)
  })
})
```

Comment: You need to adjust it for your case, for example I would be surprised if the td class was "className"

Comment: but how would I display the output?

Answer (score 0):

```
let text = await page.evaluate (() => document.querySelector('tbody').innerText)
```

Comment: I get the following error:
Error running your code. ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment

Comment: I solved the error, there is a space in between '=>'